# Django App Error "DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread" all of a sudden

Tags: python, database, django, runtime-error

refreshed the tab in my browser for my django app and got:

```
DatabaseWrapper objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread
```

it appears its happening on:  `if form.is_valid():` within:

```
def Registration(request):
    form = NewUserRegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/Login/")
    else:
        form = NewUserRegistrationForm()

    return render(request, 'register.html', {
        'form': form 
    })
```

It is very strange this all of a sudden is happening, as I didn't change anything to make it occur..

I tried clearing the cache on my browser (as suggested in my research) but this isnt fixing the situation.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was likely caused from introduced django 1.5.4 code that wasn't compatible with 1.5.1. code.